# MS Access; how to move it into inaccessible state / DSN-less table without password

Tags: security, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2013, dsn

I tried to import tables from an already opened MS Access accdb file into a new accdb file using the built in import menu, but I got an error message.
The error message said that the "admin" user has set the file in an inaccessible state. (this is my translation from Hungarian)
So I was not able to import any table or query.

**I would like to know, how to move an accdb or accde file into this inaccessible state programmatically, using VBA code.**

Reason behind: I would like to distribute a front end accde file which protects itself from anyone stealing odbc connection info, like MySQL server user and password. But the Msysobjects table can be imported into another access file.
I can create tables and queries at startup and delete them at application close, but how to prevent table & query import from it while it is running?
This inaccessible state would come handy.
**If there is another way to block table import into other access files, please let me know.**

*** Edited section: ***
**Design view trick:**

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUnused",acDesign,,,,acHidden
```

Works with accdb, table import locked while editing. As expected, doesn't work with accde.

**Connection cache approach:**
Works with queries.
**FIXED**: No matter how hard I tried, user and password has been saved with table. I provided a connect string without user and password, but it appeared in the connect string after appending the tabledef to the collection.
Method A saved the unprovided password, method B works only with manual logon.

**Remarks:** I know that storing user & password in VBA inside an accde isn't the most secure option, but.. 1. Creating a new user on server side & assigning a role might be painfully slow. (see also: beaurocracy)  2. Also handing over server credentials to a few thousand users makes social engineering easier.
Const values, even Private Const values are viewable, if you open the accde file in a text editor. Use functions instead to echo values.

Actual user and password has been replaced in the text below.
**LOGON PASS/FAIL and .Connect before/after lines were copied from debug.print output.**

I have tried two variations:

**A**:   / proposed by Albert D. Kallal /

- Delete all tables and queries, compact & repair, then restart application.
- ? tabletest: testlogon with user and pwd, then AddOneTable(MyCon) without.
- LOGON PASS
- .Connect before = ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mesterlista
- .Connect after = ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mesterlista;user=*;password=*;
- > > **User and passsword stored.**
- **Fix: after .append, reedit .Connect & relink.**

**B**:  / works with manual logon /

- Delete all tables and queries, compact & repair, then restart application.
- AddOneTable(MyCon) +  MySQL Connector/ODBC data source configuration window
- .Connect before = ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mesterlista
- .Connect after = ODBC;Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mesterlista;PORT=3306
- > > **Note that {} disappeared in driver name, also PORT appeared.**
- application restart
- ? TestLogon("ODBC;Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mesterlista;PORT=3306" & ";user=*;password=*")
- **True**
- Table isn't working, MySQL Connector/ODBC data source configuration window pops up.
- ? TestLogon("ODBC;Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mesterlista;PORT=3306") +  MySQL Connector/ODBC data source configuration window, logging in manually
- **True**
- Table is working.
- > > So this method is good if you wish for manual logon, but doesn't work with automated logon.

VBA code used for testing:

```
Public Function tabletest()

  Dim MyConWithPassWord   As String
  Dim MyCon               As String

  MyCon = "ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mesterlista"
  MyConWithPassWord = MyCon & ";user=***;password=***"
  
   If TestLogon(MyConWithPassWord) = False Then
      Debug.Print "LOGON FAIL"
      Exit Function
   End If
   
   Debug.Print "LOGON PASS"
   AddOneTable (MyCon)
   
End Function

Public Function TestLogon(strCon As String) As Boolean

   On Error GoTo TestError
   
   Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
   Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef
   
   Set dbs = CurrentDb()
   Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")
   
   qdf.Connect = strCon
   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
   
   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.
   qdf.SQL = "SELECT 1;"
   qdf.Execute
   
   TestLogon = True
   
Exit Function
   
TestError:
   TestLogon = False
      
   Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
   Debug.Print strCon

End Function


Public Function AddOneTable(strCon As String)
   On Error GoTo myerr

  Dim tdfcurrent As DAO.TableDef

  Dim LocalTable    As String      ' name of local table link
  Dim ServerTable   As String      ' name of table on SQL server

  LocalTable = "cimke"
  ServerTable = "cimke"

  Set tdfcurrent = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(LocalTable)

  tdfcurrent.SourceTableName = ServerTable
  tdfcurrent.Connect = strCon
  
  Debug.Print ".Connect before = " & tdfcurrent.Connect
  
  CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tdfcurrent
  
  CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh
  Debug.Print ".Connect after = " & CurrentDb.TableDefs(LocalTable).Connect

  ' fix: removing user / password from tabledef.connect:
  Set tdfcurrent = CurrentDb.TableDefs(LocalTable)
  tdfcurrent.Connect = strCon
  tdfcurrent.RefreshLink
 
  Debug.Print ".Connect after RELINK = " & CurrentDb.TableDefs(LocalTable).Connect



Exit Function

myerr:
   Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
   Debug.Print strCon

End Function
```

Comment: See my post below. You do NOT have to include the uid/password in the linked tables. Following the advice of my post eliminates the requirement to include the uid/password in the connection strings used in the linked tables.. That means if someone views the llinked tables connection strings, or imports them to another application, the uid/password will not show, and is not included in such strings. If user launches copy of access, imports the links, they will NOT work. So yes, you can achieve a reasonable level of security in this regards.

Comment: As I stated, this works for everyone else - that article I linked to is for MySQL. And my test code worked just fine. At this point I can't determine why this does not work for you, but for everyone else, including the article shows this works. The approach outlined works just fine. So the only issue left is why this is not working for you? I suppose if you have any "stray" user or system DNS's, I would delete those. I should not that I could NOT get  a file DSN to work for some reason, but "user/system" DSN's did work. However, we not using DSN's here. So long shot would be to remove DSN's.

Comment: The other suggest would be to try the 3.51 driver. The simple matter is everyone else is not seeing your issue or problem, and without others seeing your problem, it is rather difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: One more suggest: You don't have any other tables linked, do you? And you delete the linked table, and then exit access, right? You only want to test with the one linked table existing - and in fact on a fresh startup you don't have any linked tables, right?

Comment: and do this with a fresh new blank database. Only that code, and the results should be the one linked table.

Comment: I did it on a few new empty databases with the same results.

Comment: Grasping at straws here!. Delete any stray DNS's in the registry, but I tested this with 2010, and 2013.  As noted the articles I linked to have no such problem. Perhaps x32 vs x64 bits? Perhaps test on another computer. Really at a loss since everyone else is not having your issue or problem.  Try posting on utterAccess, - ben who wrote that article often hangs out there - and good number of MVP's. I would just ask why with the simple code the password is being pulled in. There is a table link attribute setting called dbAttachSavePWD - this allows saving password. So perhaps google that.

Comment: We have a national holiday here, so I will continue it on wednesday. I do have a file DSN, i will delete this.  I tried Createtabledef(name, dbAttachSavePWD, connectstring), IIRC it generates an error.
I will also try another computer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't believe your syntax and use of dbAttchSavePWD is correct. And keep in mind that sets the "bits" to ALWAYS save the password. So you would in theory want to XOR the value to turn those bits off in the setting. Since few if any article notes this when linking, then I VERY much doubt this is your issue, but see this article : http://gainingaccess.net/Articles/TableDefAppendOrTableDefRefreshLink.aspx

Comment: After deleting all file / user DSN for MySQL, user & password was still stored, but the relink method works. After tabledefs.append, reediting .Connect & .refreshlink fixed my problem. I have updated the main post. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for follow up. Perhaps the reason is so few see this, is that the "vast" majority code is re-link (with refresh), and not "just" adding the link as I suggested. The MySQL link code did work fine, and it not clear why an additional refresh link is required by your code - but it is a workaround. I'll likely come back here and delete most of my comments, and edit down the "long" answer to the bare min. Thus in theory, having linked tables and re-running your re-link code (as opposed to adding links) should quite much work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

You do NOT have to include the UID + password in the connection strings.

What this means is that on code start up you can execute a logon. You can either:

Embed the logon in your VBA code. Only a ONE TIME logon at start up is required and then ALL OF your existing linked tables will work, and this works EVEN WHEN the linked tables don’t have the user + password included in those connection string.

And you can use some type of encrypting, or hash code in VBA to convert the embedded user + password if you are worried about someone uses some kind of file HEX editor etc. to parse or view the contexts of the accDE file.

The other simple approach is to prompt the userid + password on start-up (ask the user for id + password). As this point you simply then execute a logon. Once that logon has been executed, then all of the linked tables will work just fine, and those linked tables DO NOT require the UID+PASSOWRD to be included, nor imbedded in those linked tables.

I cannot stress that a re-link of tables is NOT required if you do this.

The reason and trick for above is access will cache the logon ONCE a legitimate logon has occurred. ONCE a logon has occurred (a successful connection), then ALL OTHER linked tables will use this cached connection.

So, I suggest you delete all your linked tables, and then execute a logon, and then re-link all of the tables and LEAVE OUT the user + password when you do this. (Just remember to NOT include the user + password in the connection string used to link the tables. You can do this using the built-in table manager, or you can use code – either way will work.

Once you link this way, if you launch the application, the table links will NOT work, and they ONLY work AFTER you execute a logon.

What this means then if someone attempts to open, or import the table links to another database, the linked tables will not work since the linked tables do not include the user + password.

To execute a logon, use the following code:

strCon = "valid connection string PLUS USERID + PASSWORD"

So take the existing connection string (without userID/password), add to the string the userid/password, and then execute the logon code like this:

```
TestLogon(strCon)
```

The code to execute the logon is thus:

```
Function TestLogin(strCon As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.connect = strCon

   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.

   qdf.sql = "SELECT 1 as t"
   qdf.Execute

   TestLogin = True

   Exit Function

TestError:
    TestLogin = False
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Once you execute the above, then the linked tables without the user + password will now work!

If someone attempts to open, or import the table links, then the user + password will NOT be included, nor do you want to include the user + password in the connection string used to link the table.

So delete your table links. Execute the above logon code. Now re-link the tables – but do NOT choose the option to include the user + password.

If you skip the logon code above, and attempt to open a table, then you will get prompted for the userid + password by the ODBC driver. (So what kind of prompt you get will depend on how the database vendor setup their odbc drivers to handle this.

The above is all you require. The “idea” for the above code and how this works is outlined in the following article:

https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2011/04/08/power-tip-improve-the-security-of-database-connections/

However, the same code and the explain in as per above should suffice.

YOU DO NOT HAVE to include the userid + password in the linked tables, and for obvious reasons of security, you should not.

Keep in mind that near all client software needs some logon, but if you don’t embed the uid/password anywhere in the code, then the huge hole of security in regards to linked tables in Access is eliminated. If someone attempts to disassemble the application, grab the linked table connection strings etc., they WILL NOT get the password. So if one prompts at startup, logs on, and then nulls out those values, once again the uid/password is NOT embedded in the application.

Anyone can dissemble the code, and they not get the uid/password if you follow this approach in Access.

If a user imports those links, and they have the uid/password in plain view, then they will see the uid/password. However, if you link the tables without the uid/password, then there is no requirement to embed the uid/password ANYWHERE in the application to work. All that is required is to execute a valid logon using the above code - once done, then all connections will work without issue.

So before, or after executing the logon, at no point in time will the linked tables show or have the uid/password. In fact, this even includes if one is using a accDB (non compiled application). If you jump into the debug window and inspect the connection strings used for the active working linked tables, you will see that the uid/password IS NOT INCLUDED IN THE CONNECTION STRING!

The vast majority of client software systems do have to connect to a database, and if one does not include the uid/password anywhere in that code or application, then that is a "reasonable" level of security.

Here is some sample code I used:

```
Sub TEst222()

  Dim MyConWithPassWord   As String
  Dim MyCon               As String

  MyCon = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=albertkallal-pc\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=test3"

  MyConWithPassWord = MyCon & ";UID=TEST3;pwd=password"

  TestLogon (MyConWithPassWord)
  AddOneTable (MyCon)

End Sub
```

TestLogon used was:

```
Function TestLogon(strCon As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.Connect = strCon
   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.

   qdf.SQL = "SELECT 1"

   qdf.Execute

   TestLogon = True

Exit Function

TestError:
   TestLogon = False
   Exit Function

End Function
```

and to add a table link:

```
Sub AddOneTable(strCon As String)

  Dim tdfcurrent As DAO.tableDef

  Dim LocalTable    As String      ' name of local table link
  Dim ServerTable   As String      ' name of table on SQL server

  LocalTable = "MyTable"
  ServerTable = "dbo.MyTable"

  Set tdfcurrent = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(LocalTable)

  tdfcurrent.SourceTableName = ServerTable
  tdfcurrent.Connect = strCon
  CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tdfcurrent

End Sub
```

My example code is for SQL server. However the article that I link to above is rather good, and the example code was for MySQL.

Here is a MySQL example:

```
Dim MyConWithPassWord   As String
Dim MyCon               As String

MyCon = "ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=test3"

MyConWithPassWord = MyCon & ";User=TEST3;Password=TEST3"

If TestLogon(MyConWithPassWord) = False Then
   MsgBox "LOGON FAIL"
   Exit Sub
End If

AddOneTable (MyCon)
```

So you need to test if you actually logged on (that was the WHOLE point of this post).

If you are receiving a prompt during the re-link, then that means what you have is not working. THE WHOLE POINT here is to eliminate the need to logon.

Once this is working. you can launch Access, and double click on a table - the ODBC logon will prompt. However, if you execute your logon code first, then you can click on the table without a odbc logon prompt.

Comment: I explicitly specified you could dynamically link the tables at runtime, the thing you're doing, and that this doesn't offer true security since it leaves your connection string visible in the VBA. You can obfuscate it in a variety of ways, but obfuscation is not true security. My answer stands just fine.

Comment: NO NO NO NO! My example DOES NOT suggest you re-link at runtime. You link the tables WITHOUT uid+password. Once you execute the above logon (not a linked table), then ALL OF THE linked tables will NOW WORK. You DO NOT RE-LINK, and you DO NOT INCLUDE the uid+password. Can you actually read what I said? again: you do NOT re-link and you DO NOT include the uid+password for the  connection in the linked tables.

Comment: This is not different then writing a application in c++, or vb.net or anything else. Most people include the uid+password in the linked table connections - you do NOT have to do this. Read the post again: WE ARE NOT RE-LINKING the tables at runtime and WE ARE NOT INCLUDING THE UID/PASSWORD in the linked tables. If you prompt the user for uid/password and execute the above code, the all the linked tables work,and the uid/password is NOT embeeded in the code nor is it included. You ONLY ask the user for the uid/password - we are NOT including the uid/password in the linked tables.

Comment: after you execute the logon, you can null out the values you prompted the user with. If somone comes along and imports the linked table(s), the uid/password will NOT be in those connection strings.

Comment: _you only ask the user_.... The question implies the user doesn't have access to the login or password. That's why it needs to be stored in code. Of course it's not in the registry, that's only true with the _RegisterDatabase_ option. If the user has this info, of course you don't have to store it in code. I know that

Comment: This connection cache approach seems to be good. Thanks. I will test it on monday. I'm already using DSN-less tables, and I have functions to change all the .Connect strings quickly.  
    
Off topic: It is tempting to store the UID and password in the VBA code. Handing over the database credentials to all users for login might be more insecure, than having it in a VBA function inside an accde. I figured out that VBA Const values are visible when opening the front end in notepad++, but local strings in a function are not.

Comment: Note that the main question, blocking access to tables from external programs, is not fixed by this approach. `GetObject("", "Access.Application").CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("My_linked_table")`  can open a recordset to the linked table from an external application if the database is open, even though you're not storing the connection string with the table (since it uses the running application).

Comment: Sure, you can automate a copy of Outlook, and do the same thing. In fact what you state applies to any application that allows  a COM interface.  So a secure copy of QuickBooks in a corporate environments also has this issue. And EVEN in this case, it still don't allow the user to grab or lift the UID/password. So no one is arguing that com automation that is common on the desktop opens up holes such as a password protected Excel sheet, accounting packages, or in fact ANY application that supports automation. However, that was not the topic nor your point you made previous to this comment.

Comment: The simple point being made is you don't have to store the uid/password in the application, and you don't have to re-link the tables and to suggest or imply other is simply not the case.  So sure, COM automation is a well known security hole, but you had stated nothing in regards to that context, nor did the original poster. They stated the issue was imbedded uid/pass and that of users making a copy of the application.

Comment: @Eperbab - you could also munge the strings, and run some VBA converting code to decrypt - but it looks like you have this issue in hand - even if you don't want users to logon, you thus can keep the uid/password out of prying eyes quite well.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - After 6 hours of fighting, user and password still stored in tabledef.Connect string. They are automatically copied from the connection cache. I added detailed test results to the main question. Please, help.

Comment: (busy right now) So Just delete all your table links. Exit, and then re-link. when you re-link don't check the box to save the password. (because of table name change can create lots of work then you can get around this but for now, just delete the links). And keep in mind that if you at ANY point logon/connect, then you can actually re-link with wrong uid/password and it works! - so keep in mind that cached connection. You must ALWAYS but ALWAYS exit if you going to re-link (always flush that cache - only way to flush is to exit).

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - My last iteration works with manual logon, but it doesn't work with automated logon. See details in edit 2 part of my opening question. I need the automated version. Please, help, when you have time. Thanks.

Comment: As noted, can't get to this today. However, are you deleting the table links, exit, logon, and then add table links without uid/pass in the string. If you not deleting the links then a attribute is set in regards to saving + using the password. (google for info on this issue, or simply delete the links and exit). Execute the logon, and then add the links without uid/pass. If you are not deleting the links, then you going to have issues.

Comment: I added some comments + edit2. See the simple code. As I note, the article I reference is for MySQL. All of us, including Ben who wrote that article in the Access community have been doing this trick for years.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - I have copypasted that code and followed the advice to the letter. Result: linked table created with user and password in tabledef.connect. Credentials appeared, when the tabledef was appended to the table collection.  (Windows 7 Enterprise, MS Access 2013 up to date, MySQL 5.7.19,  ODBC driver 5.3.10)

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - After deleting all tables and queries and restarting access, testlogon() passes, then AddOneTable (MyCon) creates a table with user and password. I do NOT provide user or password to AddOneTable().  That's why I'm asking help since 23th april. See my last edit in my main post.

Comment: Hum, if TestLogon() is returning true, then there is something else going on here. When you  launch a linked table, or start the re-link process, you should not get a logon prompt (if you do, then you not logged in correctly before the re-link process starts). As noted, I tested the above last code sample with MySQL - and it worked fine.

Comment: I have tested two methods. With mehtod A (your suggestion), testlogon() is true, and with AddOneTable (MyCon) I do NOT get a logon prompt. The linked table is created, BUT the table .Connect contains user and password. MyCon does NOT contain user and password, so it seems, that access grabs them from the connection cache somehow.  It happens, when the table is appended to collection. *** I also listed method B, where user and password isn't added to the table, but I get a logon prompt after testlogon()=True.

Comment: I tested my code with MySQL. And that article I linked to just so happens to be MySQL also! I am really perplexed as to what is different here. Try creating a new blank db, and add just that code to a module? Making wild guesses at this point in time. Does some startup code or some macro run by accident on startup that connects before you do anything else? (like I said, really grasping at straws).  Try a blank db, and only add the test code to a module. I really trying to think or guess to add something more and I am coming up empty handed. The only difference is perhaps the driver I used?

Comment: I have created a few new accdb databases, imported the code, and tested with the same results. If the first connection reused for the table is made with manual logon, then user & password isn't stored in the table .Connect, but the table isn't working after succesfull testlogon.   
If the first connection is made without the odbc configuration window, then user & password saved to the table.  
I tried other ODBC drivers. 5.3 ANSI: access denied. (maybe because the schema is in utf8??) 8.0 unicode or ansi: error 3151.  3.51:  Connection failed: IM002.

Comment: Did you ever get this working the way you wanted?  See [Linked tables without saving password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792639/4999393) for a method to link the SQL tables while preventing the UID/PWD from being saved in the connection string.

Comment: Yes, the poster admits he got this working. The issue/problem was that when the user added the link, it was saving  the uid/password. This is strange behaviour, but the user noted that adding a extra refresh  in the code fixed this issue - we are not sure why, but the  user now has linked tables without the uid/password as part of the table links. So for some reason, adding an additional refresh link a 2nd time fixed this issue.

Comment: @JerichoJohnson I still haven't figured out, why the userid and password is copied from the connection cache to the table link, but .RefreshLink still fixes the issue. 
My next iteration for security is, that I will use a connection for tables wich has read-only rights on the server, and a 2nd connection for an unsaved pass-trough query to write changes. So the attacker will not be able to write to the database without breaking the accde. The other remaining hole is unauthorised read access.

Comment: You can't have two cached connections at the same time. It will use the one that allows read/write. Unless you exit access to clear the pwd cache. So you can never have two cahced connections - at the same (more specific, you can't control which one will be used). You really thus can only have one active connection to the one database. In fact once the pwd is cached? You can actually link with a invalid user/pwd, and it will work since it fetches the cached pwd. Only until you exit and re-enter will you now note the connections don't work. That cache cannot be cleared by code - have to exit.

Comment: So on startup, you can prompt for uid/pwd - and if that is a read only user - sure no problem. But if you execute another  a logon with read/write, then both are cached, and access will use the read/write one.  In fact if you just open any linked table with a uid/pwd in the link? Then you can now open any other linked table without even a uid/pwd. So, you not going to get control nor management of two connections at the same time