# ODBC Connection to Connect Ms Access to an Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, ldap, odbc, ms-access-2010

I need to connect an Ms Access Database to an Oracle database (I suppose via an ODBC connection).

When I connect to this Oracle database via SQL Developer (which works well), I use the following parameters:

```
LDAP server: XXX.YYY.int:18126:18127
Select Context: cn=OracleContext,dc=YYY,dc=int
DB Service: XXXPRD.
```

Now like to reproduce the same connection in the ODBC Data Source Administrator screen of WINDOWS 10.

[image]

The back-end database is an Oracle database version Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.  For this purpose I have downloaded and installed the Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2.0) 64 bit, but do not know what to do next.

Can anybody put me on the right track?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First install the Oracle ODBC driver. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-098976.html
2. If MS Access is the 32 bit version, you will need the ODBC data source administrator 32 bit version.
3. Add a file DSN or user DSN, with the Oracle driver.
4. If it works, create a linked table, and check the ODBC connection string.
5. Start to use DSN-less tables for security reasons, if you plan to deploy the front end on other computers. This example code is for MySQL, so the ODBC string will be different: [ms access; how to move it into inaccessible state / DSN-less table without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946592/ms-access-how-to-move-it-into-inaccessible-state-dsn-less-table-without-passw)