# Prevent Access linked tables being imported into new database

Tags: sql, security, ms-access, database-design, vba

I'm sure this particular problem has existed for quite some time, but unfortunately, no amount of searching anywhere on here or the internet, has lead me to a solution (scarily!).

I have a setup of multiple front-ends to a back end database, that's working just fine. I'm attempting to get IT to hand over the SQL Server access we're so desperate for, but until then, we have to secure what we can within the Access database.

The back-end is protected, and the front end is locked down with bypass keys disabled, etc, but isn't encrypted (so the user can open it).

The front end contains linked tables to the back end, so that DLookups can work, but it turns out that by doing so exposes a huge security issue.

If the user creates a new database, they can import all the linked tables and queries from the front end (the wizard prevents the forms and modules coming over from the executable file) and not only have access to the protected data, but they can actually manipulate the data too as it's linked.

Surely, this isn't a gigantic flaw in MS Access and I'm missing something here?

How can I secure the database from this type of security issue, without hopefully, having to go through and change every DLookup variable to a variable looking at a connection string SELECT query?

Comment: Review [ms access; how to move it into inaccessible state / DSN-less table without password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49946592/7296893). Note that I consider the accepted answer there to be wrong on several notes, promoting obfuscation and pseudosecurity instead of true security and being vague about it.

Comment: Please clarify - your backend is an Access database file, correct? How is it "protected" now? With an Access database password? If you did have a SQL Server backend, you could use [Linked Tables without saving password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792639/4999393)

Comment: Thanks Erik - would your Design Lock work in an ACCDE file? Or would I need to re-convert back to ACCDB to make this work?
To clarify @JerichoJohnson - it is an encrypted ACCDB Access file. The back end is encrypted with a password to open it. That's the plan, but until the political situation delivers SQL Server (which would probably also deliver Visual Studio) - our hands are tied sadly.

Comment: You're using Access as a front-end and a dev tool. Security should be implemented at the server level. This problem is analogous to complaining that Visual Studio is insecure because someone can use it to write code to access a database: the database should be secured.

Comment: @RazorKillBen It indeed only works in an accdb. I haven't yet found a reliable workaround. However, your problem occurs even when closed, and you'll need a fundamentally different approach. Linked tables should be considered public information. While Albert's answer doesn't alleviate the true problem (that a password will have to be stored somewhere accessible to the database or the database has to be password-protected), it makes it considerably more difficult to exploit.

Comment: Yes nicomp I understand that, but the back-end is secured and encrypted. I was shocked that a fresh new database import of the front-end, would carry over passwords and the like.
@ErikvonAsmuth - it's a really good solution, just so unfortunate it doesn't work with ACCDE. I agree fully with your valuation of Albert's answer - it relies as far as I can see, on the user supplying details anyway which is counter-productive to the problem. I think you're right - the better way around this will be to have no linked tables and send queries to the database from the VBA.

Comment: @RazorKillBen Albert's answer does offer a way to create a connection without passwords based on a password stored in code. That should be about as secure as using queries from VBA: both require the password to be stored in code, which leaves your password vulnerable to someone that can decompile and reverse-engineer. That "solution" at the end of my code similarly shouldn't be used: it's pseudosecurity and unsafe too.

Comment: My point is: if you're giving someone an accde that connects to an external server using a password, you're giving them that password. You can do several things to make it difficult for them to figure that out, but they still have it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not meaning to pick on you. Access is great for prototyping but it hasn't kept pace with the growth of technology and all us Access developers pay the price for that.

Comment: Not at all @nicomp - I fully understand. Unfortunately, it's the same here; SQL Server team are scared to let us put an Access FE over the server due to security (understandable) but the other teams don't want us to have Visual Studio because of... security, so we're left with the least secure solution. Unfortunately, I'm stuck trying to stick a plaster over an axe-wound, and expected to come up with a cheap perfect solution, which I knew from the start wasn't going to happen. Still, perhaps the security flaw here may fuel the argument for leaving Access behind, so appreciate both of you.

Comment: @RazorKillBen Getting meta for a moment: you are not being given the tools to do your job properly. I guess we all live that!