# MS Access / SQL Server Automatic Login

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Using Microsoft Access with a SQL Server connected. For years I have been able to run batch files that will start up code within MS Access that runs ETL. However, now it requires a SQL Server sign-in. How can I have MS Access remember my credentials so I don't have to login manually -- allowing the process to be automated?
[image]

Comment: Did you ask the person that made the authentication change? Your instance is now using mixed mode so you can use either. Otherwise, you will need to **securely** store that information within your application and it's config information somehow. But this might be more complicated since it seems you need to pass the credentials to your batch files? Are they set up for that?

Comment: @SMor Not sure how to pass through the batch files or to set up config? Not a usual MS Access user...

Comment: Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49959228/5514747) by Albert Kallal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy fix would be to delete the table links, and then re-link, and when you re-link, make sure you check this box:

[image]

That box DOES NOT re-appear on/when refreshing table links.

You can also consider caching the password, and not saving the UID/password in the table links, but for now, to eliminate the prompt(s) you receiving, you need to re-create the table links. If you have a lot of tables, then you might want to save the list of tables to a local table. but you will have to delete them to get the above prompt (save password) during a table re-link - using refresh links will not fix this issue (but VBA code can fix this).